# Symfony2/FOSRestbundle ignoring serialization groups (for array of results)

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-2.8, jms-serializer

Serialization groups work for me fine when i fetch one entity but 
when i try fetch array of results i got empty result set.

I do this like that:

```
 * @\FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View(serializerGroups={"client"})
```

but also tried manually set context on view object, and same situation.
When i don't set group or set to "Default":

```
 * @\FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View(serializerGroups={"Default"})
```

i got proper serialized result set.

My entity:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
[...]
/**
 * Document
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="documents")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\DocumentRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"DocumentListener"})
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @JMS\AccessorOrder("custom", custom = {"id", "folderId", "title"})
 */
class Document implements ResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @JMS\Groups({"client"})
     * @JMS\Expose()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="description")
     * @JMS\Groups({"client"})
     * @JMS\Expose()
     */
    protected $description;

    [...]
```

and my controller:

```
// not working
/**
 * @\FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View(serializerGroups={"client"})
 * @return Paginator
 * @Get("/documents")
 */
public function documentsAction(ParamFetcher $params)
{
    [...]
    return ($this->getPaginator(
        $params,
        $documentBundle->get()
    ));
}

//works fine
/**
 * Get document
 *
 * @QueryParam(name="id", requirements="\d+", nullable=false)
 * @param ParamFetcher $params
 * @\FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View(serializerGroups={"client"})
 */
public function documentAction(ParamFetcher $params)
{
    /** @var DocumentRepository $documentBundle */
    $documentBundle = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Document');

    return $documentBundle->findByDocumentId($params->get('id'));
}
```

PS.

```
fosrestbundle 1.7.9
jmsserializer 0.16.0
```

Comment: hey, did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue :(

Comment: i had ```$qb->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);``` in bundle. And serialization to work need real entities not arrays.